# Unity 3d: Can't enable a component on another GameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I would like to blur the background when I press pause.
My blur effect is on the Blur Effect script which is situated in the Main Camera gameobject.
The main problem is that when I press pause it gives me the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", but I have set the GameObject to its variable in Unity.

Here's what I have in the script about all this;

```
var camera:GameObject;
```

This is positioned in the Update()

```
if(paused == true){
    camera.GetComponent(BlurEffect).enabled = true;
}
if(paused == false){
    camera.GetComponent(BlurEffect).enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `camera` variable isn't initialized ("not set to an instance of an object"). Use `Camera.main` to obtain a reference to the main camera. The following line in `Update()` should be enough:

```
Camera.main.GetComponent(BlurEffect).enabled = paused;
```